# Update Mysql rows in foreach loop based on selected itemid

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am trying to update some rows in mysql based on selected checkbox,but my query is updating all the rows in the table. Please check below code:

```
    if (!empty($_POST['checkbox'])) 
    {
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach ($_POST['checkbox'] as $selected) {
            $sql1="UPDATE Items SET Status='1' WHERE Item_Id='$selected'";
            $result1=mysql_query($sql1);
            if (!$result1) 
            {
                echo "Error While updating";
            }
            else
            {
               header("Refresh: 2;url=Main_Menu.php");
               mysql_close($conn);
               echo "<p>Todays Menu Updated <a href='Main_Menu.php>Click here</a> if you     are not redirected automatically in 2 seconds<br /></p>";
           } 
       }
```

Comment: `echo $sql1="UPDATE Items SET Status='1' WHERE Item_Id='$selected'";` and shed some light on us?

Comment: can you print_r($selected) , and tell us the result please?

Comment: What is your HTML code?

Comment: Are you away of the danger of this type of query? "UPDATE Items SET Status='1' WHERE Item_Id='$selected'"? particularly when using the deprecated mysql_query() method?

Answer (score 0):

Here `if (!empty($_POST['checkbox']))` you should use the name of your checkbox.

For instance, if your html is like below:

```
  <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox_name" />
```

You should write the if statement as below:

```
if (!empty($_POST['checkbox_name']))
```

The same holds for the `foreach` statement and the use of this in your sql statement.